# C# DataGridView - event for Cell changes caused by DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there an event for when a cell value changes in a DataGridView as a result of changes in the DataSource?

I've created my own custom class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged,

```
public class CustomWorkbook : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string filepath;
    string status;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and bound it to my DataGridView  as follows,

```
BindingList<CustomWorkbook> workbookList = new BindingList<CustomWorkbook>();
BindingSource workbookBinding = new BindingSource(workbookList , null);
dataGridViewWorkbooks.DataSource = workbookBinding;
```

[image: DataGridView]

Currently the cell values update automatically as desired, but there are some more processing and aesthetic effects I'd like to add which require knowing when a cell value has changed and which cell (i.e. make UPDATED cells green, PENDING cells yellow)

I've tried the CellValueChanged event in DataGridView, but that seems to only work for user edits. The NotifyPropertyChanged event will fire when a value has changed...but it doesn't give any reference to the cell that was changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking a brute-force approach of just adding event handlers to most `DataGridView` events, I found that the `DataBindingComplete` event is what I was after. This event was raised whenever a property in my `CustomWorkbook` class was changed (I presume the `INotifyPropertyChanged` trickles through to `BindingList`, `BindingSource`, and finally `DataSource` in my `DataGridView`?).

While this event doesn't provide any references to the corresponding cell for the property that was changed, I ended up just looping through the all cells since I know the name of the column containing the cell in question.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Called whenever changes have been made to the binded list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void DataGridViews_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViews_UpdateStatusColour(sender as DataGridView);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change the colour of the cells in the column whose DataPropertyName is "Status"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="grid"></param>
    private void DataGridViews_UpdateStatusColour(DataGridView grid)
    {
        // Get the column index
        int targetColumn = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grid.Columns)
        {
            if (col.DataPropertyName == "Status")
            {
                targetColumn = col.Index;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Loop through every row, and colour the corresponding cell
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[targetColumn];
            switch (cell.Value.toString())
            {
                case ("UPDATED"):
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    break;
                case ("PENDING"):
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    break;
                case ("MISSING"):
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
                    cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
                    break;
                case ("ERROR"):
                    cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

What it looks like:

[image: DataGridView with colour]

Comment: You may want to look at the DataGridView properties SelectedCells and CurrentCell - that might help you narrow down which cell(s) were edited.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I was looking for a solution for this in my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533784/what-is-the-datagridview-event-that-is-fired-when-a-cell-value-is-changed-progra), and no one believed me that this was an issue. I just wish it actually returned the cell that was changed...