# What is the DataGridView event that is fired when a cell value is changed programmatically? (Not by user edit)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with three columns, start time, end time and duration. When a user edits the start or end time, the duration gets updated programmatically.

I'd like to capture the event that is fired when that duration column gets updated in their respective cell, since I want to do a little visual effect by animating the background colour of that cell, showing it was updated programmatically.  My `DataGridView` is not in virtual mode.

Does an event like that exist?

The `CellValueChanged` event is only fired on user edit.

Comment: _the duration automatically gets updated_ Do you do that in code? What else do you need..? or try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The CellValueChanged event is only fired on user edit. I have updated the question with more clarity.

Comment: _The CellValueChanged event is only fired on user edit._ Not true.

Comment: Well it doesn't work me. I'll make a small isolated sample file when I can.